# Issue with Devise holding sessions on Elastic Beanstalk Unauthorized error. 401 Unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devise, amazon-elb

I am deploying an app onto Amazon ELastic Beanstalk with a load balanced configuration. It utilizes an RDS for the instances run on EC2. Overall I feel it's standard and I haven't had this issue with other apps.

Successful login:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for x.x.x.x at some_time +0000
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/sessions/_form.html.haml (4.9ms)
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.haml (2.6ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (60.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_logo_image.html.haml (2.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_spinner.html.haml (1.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 349.7ms (Views: 270.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for x.x.x.x at some_time23:43:07 +0000
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"spoijsoisjosijsoisjsoisjfaketoken", "user"=>{"login"=>"username1", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) AND (`username` = 'username1' OR `email` = 'username1') LIMIT 1
  Administrator Load (1.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('Administrator') AND (`users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) AND (lower(username) = 'username1' OR lower(email) = 'username1') LIMIT 1
   (1.1ms)  BEGIN
   (1.2ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `last_sign_in_at` = 'some_time23:41:47', `current_sign_in_at` = 'some_time23:43:07', `sign_in_count` = 3690, `updated_at` = 'some_time23:43:07' WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('Administrator') AND `users`.`id` = 1
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
   (15.7ms)  COMMIT
   (1.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `topics` WHERE `topics`.`recipient_id` = 1 AND `topics`.`hidden_by_recipient` = 0 AND `topics`.`type` IN ('PrivateTopic') AND `topics`.`read` IS NULL
Redirected to https://examplewebsite.elasticbeanstalk.com/admin/users
Completed 302 Found in 394.3ms (ActiveRecord: 29.9ms)
Started GET "/admin/users" for x.x.x.x at some_time23:43:12 +0000
Processing by Admin::UsersController#index as HTML
  Administrator Load (1.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('Administrator') AND `users`.`id` = 1 AND (`users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) LIMIT 1
   (1.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL)
  User Load (3.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
  Rendered admin/users/_users.html.haml (371.6ms)
  Rendered admin/users/index.html.haml within layouts/application (435.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_logo_image.html.haml (1.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_spinner.html.haml (0.2ms)
   (2.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `topics` WHERE `topics`.`recipient_id` = 1 AND `topics`.`hidden_by_recipient` = 0 AND `topics`.`type` IN ('PrivateTopic') AND `topics`.`read` IS NULL
  Rendered shared/_public_profile.haml (7.7ms)
  Rendered shared/_admin_links.html.haml (6.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 487.9ms (Views: 454.6ms | ActiveRecord: 16.1ms)
```

Unsuccessful login:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for x.x.x.x at some_time 23:49:55 +0000
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ssdsdsdsdssonsodnusdunsdfaketoken=", "user"=>{"login"=>"username1", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) AND (`username` = 'username1' OR `email` = 'username1') LIMIT 1
  Administrator Load (1.7ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('Administrator') AND (`users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) AND (lower(username) = 'username1' OR lower(email) = 'username1') LIMIT 1
   (1.2ms)  BEGIN
   (1.3ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `last_sign_in_at` = 'some_time 23:43:07', `current_sign_in_at` = 'some_time 23:49:56', `sign_in_count` = 3691, `updated_at` = 'some_time 23:49:56' WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('Administrator') AND `users`.`id` = 1
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
   (47.4ms)  COMMIT
   (1.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `topics` WHERE `topics`.`recipient_id` = 1 AND `topics`.`hidden_by_recipient` = 0 AND `topics`.`type` IN ('PrivateTopic') AND `topics`.`read` IS NULL
Redirected to https://examplewebsite.elasticbeanstalk.com/admin/users
Completed 302 Found in 432.1ms (ActiveRecord: 64.3ms)
Started GET "/admin/users" for x.x.x.x at some_time 23:49:56 +0000
Processing by Admin::UsersController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2.4ms
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for x.x.x.x at some_time 23:49:57 +0000
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/sessions/_form.html.haml (2.8ms)
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.haml (0.4ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (5.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_logo_image.html.haml (1.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_spinner.html.haml (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 21.3ms (Views: 18.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
```

I can only login using an obscure browser, Mantra. Firefox, Chrome and Safari all get the 401 unauthorized redirect.

Gem list:

```
aasm (3.0.16)
actionmailer (3.2.16)
actionpack (3.2.16)
active_model_serializers (0.8.1)
active_utils (1.0.5)
activemerchant (1.18.1)
activemodel (3.2.16)
activerecord (3.2.16)
activeresource (3.2.16)
activesupport (3.2.16)
acts_as_commentable (4.0.0)
akami (1.2.0)
arel (3.0.3)
attr_required (1.0.0)
aws-sdk (1.8.1.2)
axiom-types (0.0.5)
bcrypt (3.1.7)
bitly (0.8.1)
blankslate (3.1.2)
braintree (2.23.0)
bugsnag (1.6.4)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.9.6)
cancan (1.6.7)
chronic (0.9.1)
cocaine (0.4.2)
coercible (1.0.0)
countries (0.8.4)
country-select (1.1.1)
crack (0.4.1)
createsend (1.1.1)
curb (0.8.6)
currencies (0.4.2)
daemons (1.1.9)
dante (0.2.0)
delayed_job (4.0.0)
delayed_job_active_record (4.0.0)
descendants_tracker (0.0.3)
devise (3.2.4)
devise_invitable (1.3.5)
diff-lcs (1.2.4)
dotenv (0.9.0)
dotenv-rails (0.9.0)
email_validator (1.3.0)
ensure-encoding (0.1)
equalizer (0.0.9)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.3)
execjs (1.4.0)
ey_config (0.0.6)
faraday (0.8.7)
gyoku (1.0.0)
haml (4.0.3)
haml-rails (0.4)
hashie (1.2.0)
hike (1.2.3)
hpricot (0.8.6)
httparty (0.11.0)
httpauth (0.2.0)
httpi (2.0.2)
i18n (0.6.9)
ice_nine (0.11.0)
jimson-temp (0.9.5)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.1.4)
jquery-ui-rails (2.0.2)
json (1.8.1)
jwt (0.1.8)
mail (2.5.4)
meta_search (1.1.3)
mime-types (1.25.1)
mini_magick (3.4)
mini_portile (0.5.2)
minitest (4.7.5)
minitest-rails (0.9.2)
money (5.1.1)
multi_json (1.10.1)
multi_xml (0.5.4)
multipart-post (1.2.0)
mysql2 (0.3.15)
newrelic_rpm (3.5.7.59)
nokogiri (1.6.1)
nori (2.1.0)
oauth (0.4.7)
oauth2 (0.8.1)
omniauth (1.1.4)
omniauth-facebook (1.4.1)
omniauth-linkedin (0.1.0)
omniauth-oauth (1.0.1)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)
omniauth-twitter (1.0.0)
orm_adapter (0.5.0)
paperclip (3.3.1)
paypal-express (0.5.5)
paypal-sdk-adaptivepayments (1.110.0)
paypal-sdk-core (0.2.9)
pdfkit (0.5.4)
polyamorous (0.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.5)
postmark (1.0.1)
postmark-rails (0.5.2)
psych (1.3.4)
quiet_assets (1.0.2)
rack (1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.4)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.16)
rails3_acts_as_paranoid (0.2.5)
railties (3.2.16)
rake (10.3.2)
rdoc (3.12.2)
responders (0.9.3)
rest-client (1.6.7)
restclient_with_cert (0.0.8)
rspec-core (2.13.1)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
rspec-rails (2.13.2)
safe_yaml (0.9.5)
sampler (0.0.3)
sanitize (2.0.4)
sass (3.2.9)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
savon (2.2.0)
settingslogic (2.0.9)
simple_form (2.1.1)
simple_oauth (0.2.0)
sitemap_generator (4.1.0)
sprockets (2.2.2)
stripe (1.10.1)
stripe-ruby-mock (1.10.1.5)
strong_parameters (0.2.3)
subexec (0.2.3)
thin (1.5.1)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.4)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
twitter (4.8.1)
tzinfo (0.3.39)
uglifier (2.1.1)
uuidtools (2.1.4)
validation_reflection (1.0.0)
virtus (1.0.1)
warden (1.2.3)
wasabi (3.1.0)
whenever (0.8.2)
will_paginate (3.0.4)
xml-simple (1.1.3)
```

ELB is using a self-signed ssl cert in a staging environment with a load balancer enables with sticky sessions of 600 seconds long. During this testing though there is only one instance in use due to no load. There are no JS errors and the account is valid. The fact that it is only successfully logging in in Mantra is extremely unusual. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you discovered what was happening?

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this problem myself and it was due to having different secret keys on each server.

To test if you have separate keys on each server:

- SSH directly on to one of the instances
- Navigate to /var/app/current and open the rails console with the `rails c` command.
- Type `Applicationname::Application.config.secret_key_base` with your applications name in place of Applicationname
- Take note of the value that is returned
- Follow the same steps on the other instance and compare the keys

If the keys are the same then unfortuantly something else is wrong and the following will not help. If they are different like they were in my case then you need to see how you are setting the secret key in your code.

One way you could setup your key is to use an environment variable. [This article tells you how you can set that up with EBS.](https://medium.com/@jatescher/how-to-set-up-a-rails-4-1-app-on-aws-with-elastic-beanstalk-and-postgresql-66d4e3412629)

> **Configuring secrets.yml** 
>   By default Rails now includes a secrets.yml
>   file and your production keys and settings should be set there as
>   environment variables. The default environment only requires a
>   SECRET_KEY_BASE variable to be defined, so let’s add that to your
>   environment. First run:
>
> `$ bundle exec rake secret
>   5387fca6a0a69d945bb57e8be5bce3a119292216dfc95b270275c518641aa3e8db14a5ead261b1d50332a92ed860c544ef24356100ccb391507b1c5b8d46f39b`
>
> Then go to console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/home and in
>   blog-env on the left under configuration click on the cog next to
>   ‘Software Configuration’. At the bottom, enter SECRET_KEY_BASE on the
>   left and the output of rake secret on the right.

If you want to learn more about what the secret key does, [here is an article about how it works and how it can be exploited](http://robertheaton.com/2013/07/22/how-to-hack-a-rails-app-using-its-secret-token/).

I hope this helps!